# Using Dlookup in the Default Value field of a form control

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to populate a form controls default value based on the value of a combobox on that form. The combobox is called Title, and I want the control HIPAA to populate based on the value of HIPAA in my table tblTrainingEventTiles where the Title selected on the form matches the title in the table.

I was putting the following code into the default value of the control on the form:

```
=IIf(IsNull([Title]),0,DLookUp("HIPAA","tblTrainingEventTitles","[tblTrainingEventTitles].[Title]=[Title]"))
```

Access seems to ignore it however. It doesn't do anything and there are no error messages. I'm not sure if my problem is with my dlookup or with the fact that I'm trying to use this in the default value field. (or both?) Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It seems that you use wrong way to solve your task. Because `default value` is used  when you insert new record, but the formula for it is calculated when form is opened. May be you can use `BeforeInsert` event of form or `Change` event of combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=Nz(DLookUp("HIPAA","tblTrainingEventTitles","[tblTrainingEventTitles].[Title]=[Title]"),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your combobox's bound column is text you should use ' around it's content. And you should concatenate value of combobox to filter part of `dlookup`.

```
=IIf(nz([Title],"")="",0,DLookUp("HIPAA","tblTrainingEventTitles","[tblTrainingEventTitles].[Title]='" & [Title] & '"))
```